# How to provide Up Navigation using SearchView widget in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a `SearchView` widget in my main activity and I want to enable ancestral navigation (up navigation on app's icon) when the user clicks on the search icon. I also want it to disappear when the `SearchView` closes. The below figure shows exactly what i want:

[image]

For a live example you can consider the android play store app.

Answer (score 1):

To enable ancestral navigation just use:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and do whatever you want (i.e. clearing the search field) on your onOptionsItemSelected, for instance:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {           

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            // clear search field
            return true; 
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: When i `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` the arrow appears always. I want the up arrow to be shown only when the search view is open and vice-versa.

Comment: You could listen for the search view's events and hide it when it's no longer focused: getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);